# installing Opencv on Mac Catalina

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have successfully installed opencv 4.3.0 on my Mac OS Catalina, python 3.8 is installed also, but when I try to import `cv2`, I get the `Module not found` error.
Please how do I fix this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `pip install opencv-python`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having issue with installing opencv in my Macbook - python version 3.6 ( i downgraded it for TF 2.0) and MacOs Mojave 10.14. Brew , conda and pip - none of the three seemed to work for me. So i went to [https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#files] and downloaded the .whl that was suitable for my combo of python and MacOs versions. Post this navigated to the folder where it was downloaded and executed `pip install ./opencv_python-4.3.0.36-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl`